# Calculate the weeks between 2 dates manually in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to calculate the number of months and weeks since a particular date instead of from the beginning of the year.

It shouldn't follow calendar months but should instead count a month as every 4 weeks, and begin from a specified date. I need to be able to display the number of months, and also what week it is (1, 2, 3 or 4).

I want to put in a start date, and have it then count what month and week is it from that start date e.g if the start date is set to Mon 1st August it should show Month 1, Week 1 and so on.

My code is below. I tested it with some different start dates. Here's a list of what the code below generates and what it ***should*** display

Jun-20: Should be Week 2 - Shows as Week 0

Jun-27: Should be Week 1 - Shows as Week 3

Jul-04: Should be Week 4 - Shows as Week 2

Jul-11: Should be Week 3 - Shows as Week 1

Jul-18: Should be Week 2 - Shows as Week 0

```html
$monthNumber          = 5;
$monthStartDate       = '2016-06-13';
$currentStartWeekDate = date('l') != 'Monday' ? date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last monday")) : date("Y-m-d"); // get the current week's Monday's date

$weekDateCounter      = $monthStartDate;
$currentWeekNumber    = 0;

while ($weekDateCounter != $currentStartWeekDate){
  $currentWeekNumber += 1;
  $weekDateCounter    = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($weekDateCounter . "+7 days"));
  
  //
  if ($currentWeekNumber == 4){
    $currentWeekNumber  = 0; // reset week number
    $monthNumber       += 1; // increment month number
  }
}
```

I am really at a loss with this and could use any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach seems overly complicated:

```
function weekCounter($startDate,$endDate=null){

    //use today as endDate if no date was supplied
    $endDate = $endDate? : date('Y-m-d');

    //calculate # of full weeks between dates
    $secsPerWeek = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
    $fullWeeks = 
            floor((strtotime($endDate) - strtotime($startDate))/$secsPerWeek);

    $fullMonths = floor($fullWeeks/4);
    $weeksRemainder = $fullWeeks % 4; // weeks that don't fit in a month

    //increment from 0-base to 1-base, so first week is Week 1. Same with months
    $fullMonths++; $weeksRemainder++;

    //return months and weeks in an array
    return [$fullMonths,$weeksRemainder];
}
```

You can call the function this way, and capture months and weeks:

```
//list() will assign the array members from weekCounter to the vars in list
list($months,$weeks) = weekCounter('2016-06-07'); //no end date, so today is used

//now $months and $weeks can be used as you wish
echo "Month: $months, Week: $weeks"; //outputs Month: 2, Week: 2
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/qY2OX)

Comment: This is awesome thank you! Apologies I realise I wasn't as clear as I could be in my original question. I want to return a result like in your example, however I want it to update automatically for each week.

Comment: @superhappybunnycat this will update automatically.  It's a function so you just feed it the start date and the end date you want it it will give you the right result. If you call the function with different weeks, the results will automatically update. See the live demo that I linked

Comment: It does not appear to be working properly :( It is similar to my code in that it includes a week zero when it shouldn't, and doesn't display week 4

Months: 1, Weeks: 0
Months: 1, Weeks: 1
Months: 1, Weeks: 2
Months: 1, Weeks: 3

Also, I had hoped to enter a start date and then put it on my site and leave it and have the weeks update automatically (without having to keep putting in the end date)

Comment: If the `endDate` is always the same, then modify the function so that it only takes the `startDate`. Inside the function, you can set the `endDate` variable to whatever fixed value you want.  As for unexpected results, please give me two specific dates that the function doesn't work on, and what you expected to get as a result

Comment: As an example, if I put in a start date of Mon 1st Aug, and an end date of Sunday 28th of August I would expect to see Week 1. Currently it shows week 3 when you put that in.

With the same start and end date, I would expect it to show the following week based on the date in the calendar:

When it is Monday 8th Aug - updates to Week 2
When it is Monday 15th Aug - updates to Week 3
When it is Monday 22nd Aug - updates to Week 4

Comment: I had a go editing it to remove the end date, however I seem to be getting the same issue :(

Comment: @superhappybunnycat maybe I didn't understand what you wanted. your title said *"Calculate weeks between 2 dates"* and from your question and code it seemed you wanted the number for full weeks from the first monday to the monday of the last week.  From Mon Aug 1 to Sun Aug 28, there are 3 full weeks (monday aug 1 to monday aug 22), that's why the function says `Weeks: 3`.  Why do you expect to see `Week 1`?

Comment: Oooooooh I see. You are right I haven't been clear in what I've asked for. I want to show what week it is within a set of 4 weeks. So if the month started on 1st August, that would be week 1, and the week of 8th of August would be week 2 and so on. After week 4 it would reset to week 1 again as it's a new 'month'

So if I had a start date of Mon 4th July it would show:
Month 2, Week 1

Comment: @superhappybunnycat I see.  So how is Aug 28 `Week 1` if the start date is `Aug 1`? I would expect `Week 4` because:  `Mon Aug 1 to Sun Aug 7 = week 1`, `Mon Aug 8 to Sun Aug 14 = week 2`, `Mon Aug 15 to Sun Aug 21 = week 3`, `Mon Aug 22 to Sun Aug 28 = week 4`

Comment: That is correct! If the start date was Aug 1st and the date was Aug 28 I would expect to see Week 4 as well

Comment: @superhappybunnycat Ok I've updated my answer to fit your needs. If your end date is fixed, it doesn't matter. Just pass that value to the function. For example for today, pass `'2016-08-02'` as the `$endDate` argument.

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so much. Is there a way to make it show todays date as the end date automatically? I tried both of the below. Option 2 doesn't work and option 1 returns Month: -602, Week: 1

}
$startDate = '2016-03-21';
$endDates = ['2016-08-08','date("Y-m-d")'];
foreach($endDates as $endDate) echo weekCounter($startDate,$endDate)."\n";




    $today = date("Y-m-d");
}
$startDate = '2016-03-21';
$endDates = $today;
foreach($endDates as $endDate) echo weekCounter($startDate,$endDate)."\n";

Comment: @superhappybunnycat I've modified the function to use today as the end date if you don't supply one, so you can just call it with the start date: `weekCounter('2016-07-04')`. I also updated the demo.  You will get negative results only if your start date is later than your end date.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks so much for all your help with this!

Comment: If I want to use this in my page with a PHP if statement how could I do that? I've tried using the below but it's not working.

<?php if($weeksRemainder == '4'): ?>
   Week 4 content
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: @superhappybunnycat you cannot see a function's internal variables from outside the function. If you need access to them, modify the function accordingly.  For example I've changed my answer so that it returns the months and weeks. I also show you how to use it here and the updated demo.

Comment: Oooooohhh right right. I understand now. I feel like I have learnt a lot. I have it working perfectly now. Thanks so much again ^_^

Answer (score 0):

The DateTime classes could make this much simpler for you.  Documentation for them is here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Try this out:

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2016-04-01');
$date2 = new DateTime('2016-07-24');

$diff = $date1->diff($date2);

$daysInbetween = $diff->days;
$weeksInbetween = floor($diff->days / 7);
$monthsInbetween = floor($weeksInbetween / 4);

print "Days inbetween = $daysInbetween" . PHP_EOL;
print "Weeks inbetween = $weeksInbetween" . PHP_EOL;
print "Months inbetween = $monthsInbetween" . PHP_EOL;

print "Total difference = $monthsInbetween months and "
    . ($weeksInbetween - ($monthsInbetween * 4)) . " weeks" . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Apologies I realise I wasn't as clear as I could be in my original question. I want to return a result like in your example, however I want it to update automatically for each week.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    /**
     * AUTHOR : VEDAVITH RAVULA
     * DATE : 13122019
     */
     function get_weeks($startDate = NULL,$endDate = NULL)
    {
            if(is_null($startDate) && is_null($endDate))
            {
                $startDate = date('Y-m-01');
                $endDate = date('Y-m-t');
            } 

                $date1 = new DateTime($startDate);
                $date2 = new DateTime($endDate);

                $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
                $weeks = floor(($interval->days) / 7);

                if(($date1->format("N") > 1) && ($date1->format("D") != "Sun"))
                {
                   $diffrence = "-".( $date1->format("N"))." Days";
                   $date1 = $date1->modify($diffrence);
                }
                    for($i = 0; $i <= $weeks; $i++)
                    {   
                        if($i == 0)
                        {
                            $start_date = $date1->format('Y-m-d');
                            $date1->add(new DateInterval('P6D'));

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $date1->add(new DateInterval('P6D'));
                        }
                        echo $start_date." - ".$date1->format('Y-m-d')."\n";
                        $date1->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
                        $start_date = $date1->format('Y-m-d');
                    }

        
    }

    //function call
get_weeks("2021-11-01", "2021-11-14");
```